# Why are the derivatives of complementary angles negative?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

I’m taking Calculus in highschool and my teacher told us a special trick she learnt was that the derivatives of all the trigonometric functions starting with “c” (such as cosine, cotangent, cosecant) give you a negative value. She claimed there was no mathematical reasoning behind this but that does not make sense. Is there a proof or reason as to why this is true?

Comment: The derivatives do not "give you a negative value", you probably meant that that there is a "minus" sign in front. I would say that that the math is the reason for that minus sign. Using complimentary angles, $\cos x=\sin (90^\circ-x)$ and when you take derivative and apply the chain rule, that minus comes from $(90^\circ-x)'$

Comment: I think your teacher may simply be stating that her 'c' mnemonic will be useful for the Cos(x), Cot(x), Csc(x) examples you'll encounter in class, but it doesn't imply that all co-functions are inherently/mathematically required to follow the same pattern. (e.g. some rarely used trig functions like Covercosine(x) has a derivative of +Cos(x) which doesn't fit the mnemonic, and similarly for Cosh(x) with derivative +Sinh(x), etc.)

Comment: @Vasili Maybe better to write $\frac{\pi}2$ instead of $90^\circ,$ so that the reader/OP isn't encouraged to write the [false equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4314974/21813) $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sin (90^\circ-x)=-\cos(90^\circ-x).$

Comment: @ryang Only false if we interpret $\sin$ and $\cos$ as actually being some weird versions of those functions that take inputs as degrees. I think a common alternative is to say that ${}^\circ$ is a symbol that means "multiply by $\frac{\pi}{180}$" in which case $90^\circ = \frac\pi2$ and the equality is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Misha Vasili wrote $(90^\circ-x)'$ together with $\cos x=\sin (90^\circ-x),$ which strongly suggests that they are taking derivatives of the weird-degrees-mode trig functions rather than the natural trig functions. My point is that since *the uninitiated* will blithely fail to realise that conversion to radian mode is required for formulae like $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$ to apply, using degrees while discussing derivatives of trig functions is bad paedagogical practice (unless the intention is specifically to warn that $\sin$ and $\sin_{\text{deg}}$ aren't interchangeable while taking derivatives).

Answer (score 8):

Since $$\cos(x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)\\
\csc(x)=\sec\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)\\
\cot(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right),$$ by the chain rule with $u=\frac{\pi}2-x$,
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\cos(x)=\color\red-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}\sin(u)=\color\red-\sin(x)\\
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\csc(x)=\color\red-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}\sec(u)=\color\red-\csc^2(x)\cos(x)\\
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\cot(x)=\color\red-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}\tan(u)=\color\red-\csc^2(x).$$

P.S. The first three identities, in words, mean that sine and cosine are [cofunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofunction) of each other; as are secant and cosecant; as are tangent and cotangent.

P.P.S. The red minus signs at the front of those expressions do *not* imply that they evaluate to negative values, just like the expression $-x$ is positive for $x=-5.$ (Think of `-` as a sign-flipping arithmetical operator rather than the adjective ‘negative’.)