# How does $s=r\theta$ take into account negative angles or angles greater than $2\pi$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, angle

Radian is defined as the angle subtended by the arc at the center of the circle.

The formula of radian is $\theta=\dfrac sr$ where $s$ is the arc length and $r$ is the circle's radius.

Since length of arc cannot be more than the circumference, how is a value of radian that is more than $2\pi$ adjusted in the formula?

How about a negative value of radian?

Is a scalar $k$ multiplied in the formula to compensate for negative value and for value more than to $2\pi\;?$ Is this formula correct? $$\theta=k\frac sr$$

Comment: $s = r\theta$ is better thought of as an angular displacement than arc length strictly speaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can continue using the $$s=r\theta$$ formula even when the **angular displacement** $\theta$ rad is negative or exceeds $2\pi$ rad: while the radius $r$ is positive, the **signed distance $s$ travelled along the circumference** is negative if and only if the travel direction is clockwise.

To elaborate: think of a thread spooling around its reel, where the thread is winding around the reel *multiple* times; if spooling is considered to be in the positive direction, then unspooling is considered to be in the *negative* direction.

---

**Addendum** (migrating up my comment replies)

1. $s$ is not displacement.

   [Measuring turns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275331/why-is-the-radius-chosen-for-radians/4275902#4275902)
2. $s$ and $\theta$ are scalars, not vectors in 3D space (though they can be framed as one-dimensional vectors).

   They do not have *free* direction in 3D space; their direction is *conceptual*.

   [Scalars and Euclidean vectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/621711/8446)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine walking around the circle a distance of $l$. If $l$ is positive, you walk clockwise. If $l$ is negative, you walk counterclockwise. If $l$ is more than $2\pi$, you walk around the circle multiple times. Then, if your initial location is $A$, the circle has center $O$ and radius $r$, and your final location is $B$, then you could say that angle $AOB$ is $l/r$ radians.

Adding $2\pi$ doesn’t affect things, so you generally add or subtract that until you get a number in the range $0$ to $2\pi$. If you’re given an angle to begin with, and calculate the radian using the circumference, you’ll always get a number in that range.

Comment: But since l is distance, it cannot be negative.so how can the formula radian =l/r accommodate negative value of radian. Furthermore, The value of radian more than 2pi becomes more apparent in physics when you calculate the angle subtended by the object in circular motion. Suppose the object complete two revolutions, then the angle subtended by it will be 4pi radian. But since radian=l/r(l=length of arc,which cannot be more than 2pir)how can the value 4pi be represented using this formula.that was why I was suggesting to multiply scalar k in formula so that it becomes k.l/r

Comment: Adding a scalar doesn’t make sense. My point is that your formula is incomplete. It says that if you’re given an angle, then how you can calculate radians, but it doesn’t define what radians mean in general, and it doesn’t show what it means for radians to be big or for radians to be signed. Walking around a circle is a better anology with negative radians corresponding to walking the other way, just like negative numbers on a real line go left instead of right. $4\pi$ means you walk around the circle twice, so it’s the exact same angle as 0 where your two lines in the angle are the same line.

Comment: I understand your analogy of walking in a circle and making anti-clockwise positive and clockwise negative direction, and I also understand it  intuitively. But I am more concerned about the formula of radian=l/r.I am not able to understand how can I represent negative radian and radian more than 2pi through formula since l,r are both positive and l cannot be greater than 2pi.how will you represent negative angle using this formula ?

Comment: "But since l is distance, it cannot be negative". How do you think your bank handles both deposits and withdrawals on your account? They don't say "it is a quantity of money. How can it be negative?"